# How does memory allocation works in adding a node in the beginning of a linked list?

Tags: c#, memory-management, linked-list

I'm learning linked lists and I was looking over [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/) article and I do not understand exactly how the memory allocation works when a new node is added at the beginning of a linked list.

In the article is specified that the `newNode.next` points to `head` and then `head` becomes `newNode`. What I do not understand is that, if `newNode.next` points to `head` and then `head` becomes `newNode`, this does not mean that `newNode.Next` points to itself? Is there a new copy of `head` created in `newNode.next`?

I do not understand how a new copy could be created as per my understanding all memory allocations should be done by reference, not by copy.

Comment: It's simple, really. Think of it with an example: you have `A -> B -> C`, and you want to add D at the beginning, so you do `D -> A -> B -> C`, and your `Head` just points to D instead of A, which means it's just a reference change. Also, I'd highly suggest to keep away from GeeksForGeeks if you plan to actually learn.

Comment: Ah, "all memory allocations should be done by reference, not by copy." - you are not aware that a link node is a class, hence a reference type, so "variable a = b" puts a REFERENCE to be into the variable and does not make a copy? Seems like you need to read up on the difference between reference and value types (classes and structs).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you have any other better resources for learning ?

Answer (score 1):

As @Camilo Terevinto alluded to, you are only updating one reference at a time. Here's a visualization of what is happening:

Let's say the original list is A->B->C. Head is assigned the same reference as A.

You create a new node D. Its pointers aren't set yet, so it's not connected to the original list. D  A->B->C

You set `D.next` to A. This connects it to the rest of the list. D->A->B->C.
Finally, you update the reference of head to D. Now, if we traverse the list, D will be the first node we see.